# Where authenticate user - Game Center

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I'm developing a game using cocos2d.
What is the best location to authenticate user in Game Center?

I'm using GameCenterManager provided by apple ([GKTapper](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html)).
is it ok to call authenticateLocalUser during applicationDidFinishLaunching in AppDelegate or it is to heavy for initialization process? I know that authentication is made in background, but could it affect startup performance somehow?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your game would have some sort of video-intro then you better authenticate user after everything has been shown. For example, where user is about to press "Start"

Comment: I see what you mean. But in the main menu I also have two buttons to access Achievements and Leaderboard which are presented in modal view.So if user press one of those, I guess it would be better if he is authenticated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You kind of answered your own question. I think that most people who know what they are doing put it in  applicationDidFinishLaunching, because if they have it in the init, it will result in a slightly longer loading period. Also, by putting it in the init, you may find that when the local player has been authenticated, it shall cause lag which you do not want in the middle of the menu screen.

Comment: I didn't had any experience with the game center until now. I guess I will continue working this way and maybe in the future I will make some improvements. Thanks.